# How to detect if camera is unplugged from CSI bus when it is running?

Tags: camera, qt

I am having an issue as below.

I make a Qt application to show video got from the camera module. And when showing video, if the camera is unplugged from CSI bus, I must know that and show a warning on the screen like "Camera is unplugged!".

Is there any solution to know if the camera is unplugged from CSI bus when it is running? By Qt API or Linux command.

Comment: What software gets the video stream.  Doesn't it get an error status when the camera is unplugged?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vcgencmd get_camera` in console, it will give you an output like:

```
$ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=2, detected=0
```